# Eclipse mess up intendation

Tags: eclipse

My code looks good in Eclipse, but when I push it to github it's a mess.
My code in eclipse:

[image]

and my code on Github:

[image]

Like you can see the code is (almost) good viewed in Eclipse. But it is a disaster on Github.

This are my settings in eclipse:
[image]

Is this a know problem with eclipse? With netbeans my code looks very well both in the IDE and on github. But I think I prefer Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

PS. For the project I'm working on it's necessary to work with tabs (4spaces).

EDIT: Here is another exmaple:

Eclipse:
[image]

Gedit:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a disaster on Github"? The only difference I see is the number of spaces your tab chars are expanded to and a diffent highlighting/coloring scheme. Anything else? Both is more or less unimportant.

Comment: The inconsistency. Rule 32-59 have a large indention and rule 33-43 a small one, and then rule 36 again a large one.

Comment: You are probably mixing space based and TAB based indents. In our company we force developers to use AnyEdit Eclipse plugin and configure it to always convert leading TABs to 4 spaces.